# Visual studio code extension not working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Hi i have installed Visual Studio Code. i can't download plugins from internal extension manager however, i am able to install it by using files downloaded from marketplace. After installation it shows in installed extensions, (Python and Code-Runner) but doesn't work.
For example not single one shortcut from code-runner works. I tried to reinstall but didn't help. Can someone please advice on this?

Comment: If you get error messages (from logs?), please include verbatim in your question. What is the most basic operation of each extension you tried, and what exactly happened?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess i have found solution i have just copied folder from .extensions into C:\Program Files\VS Code ....extensions.

Comment: Glad to know that you have resolved this issue, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issue. Have a nice day.

Comment: I have faced the same issue with Mac, someone please help?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. I need the watch Sass extension but it is not working.